# cannot edit Android EditText inside the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView with EditText in each row. So I cannot type anything in any EditText as well as not focus when tap on them.
Xml souce:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/textValue"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="37dip"
android:editable="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:gravity="left|center"
android:inputType="text">
</EditText>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to focus on the `EditText`s, remove the lines that set it as non-editable:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TableLayout` instead of `ListView` because `EditText` has focusable problems in `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

you made the EditText unfocusable with those two lines:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

just remove or set the value to "true" in order to use them